# Django NoReverseMatch at http://127.0.0.1:8000/boards/1/new/

Tags: django, url

This is my site urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('boards.urls'))
]
```

And this is my app urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('boards/<int:pk>',views.board_topic,name='board_topic'),
    path('boards/<int:pk>/new/',views.new,name='new_topic')
]
```

This is the Views for app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
from .models import Board
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    board = Board.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{
        'board':board,
    })
def board_topic(request,pk):
    # try:
    #     board = Board.objects.get(pk=pk)
    # except:
    #     raise Http404
    board = get_object_or_404(Board,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'topics.html',{
        'board':board
    })
def new(request,pk):
    boards = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {
        'board' : boards
    })
```

when I try to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/boards/1/new/ then this error occurs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSyLP.png)

please help me.

Comment: as I can suppose the problem not with the view but exists in a template so please add your template code especially the part when you probably redirect user to 'home'

Comment: you are right it was in templates i was using the {% url 'home' %} path wrong in my <a> tag it took me sometime but i finally got it

Comment: please attach an edit to your post where you show your html and I will post an answer so other can use this as a learning source - this is quite popular problem as I can see on stackoverflow

Comment: Please add  complete version of your app's urls and your base urls (which is in the conf directory of your project near `settings.py`) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how I was able to get rid of my error**

In my app's url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('boards/<int:pk>',views.board_topic,name='board_topic'),
    path('boards/<int:pk>/new/',views.new,name='new_topic')
]
```

*In the second path I was using name= 'board_topic'*
*and in my templates file i was using url as href = ' url "board.pk board_topics" '*
so that was why i was getting that error .
THANK YOU TO EVERYONE WHO RESPONDED